# Python Libreria Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

estoy trabajando con la libreria requests y al tratar de ingresar a la pagina que quiero scrapear se queda esperando la respuesta y nunca ingresa.

alguien me podria ayudar a ver que me hace falta? Les envio la parte del codigo que me genera este error por obvias razones elimine la pagina que estoy tratando de ingresar.

```
from requests import Session

with Session() as s:
    site = s.get('https://XXXX')
    bs_content = bs(site.content, 'html.parser')
    login_data = {'username': username,'password':password}
    s.post(payment,login_data)
    home_page = s.get('https://XXXX')
```

Comment: algunas  paginas tienen metodos para poder *evitar* el scrapping, deberias ver si la pagina admite este tipo de logueos

Comment: Como puedo ver eso?